# How to activate a Method of a Class based on Class.forName ? [Java]

Tags: java

There is an issue int trying to activate a method of a class via `Class.forName`.

*Class:*

```
public class example{
    private int number;
    
    static {
        System.out.println("example initializing");
    }
    
    example(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
    public void printFunc() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}



public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       Class<?> oc = Class.forName("example");
       oc.printFunc();  //doesnt work
    }
}
```

**Issue:** `static`  initializiation is printed, however, when trying to activate the `printFunc`, there is an error: `printFunc is undefined for the type Class<capture#5-of ?>`

**Question:** How to activate a function of a `Class` via `Class.forName` ?

Comment: Class names should begin in uppercase, so they don't get confused with variable names, which begin in lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [method invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) from reflection:

```java
try {
    Class<?> exampleClass = Class.forName("example");
    Object exampleObject = exampleClass.newInstance();
    Method printFunctionMethod = exampleObject.getClass().getMethod("printFunc");
    printFunctionMethod.invoke(exampleObject);
}
catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Thank you @iswailyildiz. It does work but only if you remove the construct of example class. Without the construct the function is going to be invoked, with it, there is going to be an `Error` in the `catch` part: `java.lang.InstantiationException`